# Show/hide tables or divs for a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tabular

This was an answer I got recently but the topic has died down and I have a few more questions to ask about it:

"That's quite a common request. Here is one way

- Break your form in pages using `div`s with easy to manage `id`s and only the first one visible

.

```
<form action=".." ..>
<!-- the first page has style set to be visible -->
<div id="formpage_1" style="visibility: visible; display: block; .."> 
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- NEXT button -->
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(1,2);">
</div>
<!-- the 2nd and following pages have style set to be invisible -->
<div id="formpage_2"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none; ..">
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons -->
  <input type="button" value="back" onclick="pagechange(2,1);">
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(2,3);">
</div>
...
<div id="formpage_10"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none; ..">
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- PREVIOUS and SUBMIT buttons -->
  <input type="button" value="back" onclick="pagechange(10,9);">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

- Use a simple JS function to switch between the pages

.

```
function pagechange(frompage, topage) {
  var page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+frompage);
  if (!page) return false;
  page.style.visibility='hidden';
  page.style.display='none';

  page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+topage);
  if (!page) return false;
  page.style.display='block';
  page.style.visibility='visible';

  return true;
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to use a table layout, break the for into more tables (one for each page) and give the `id`s to the tables instead of the `div`s"

Now the above works, when using divs, but when I use tables it doesn't work properly. The back, next buttons show all the time whether hidden or not and they always appear at the top. Any way to prevent this as I don't want to re-style everything now that I am using divs as opposed to tables.

Also when I click next and I'm at the bottom of a form it will take me to the middle/bottom of the next. Is there a way to link it to the top each time someone clicks back/next?

Comment: I strongly suggest you remove all visibility usage and only use display or vice versa. Visibility is only used if you want the hidden items to take up space in the page

Comment: yep, seems to work without so ive just removed it thanks. Hopefully this doesn't affect anything as it all seems fine :)

Comment: So how do you show and hide the table parts? I suggest you add IDs to the ROWS and hide/show those if you MUST use tables (not recommended)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perhaps it helps you?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <script>


    function pagechange(currentPage) {
     var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
     for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
       if(divs[i].id!=('formpage_'+(parseInt(currentPage)+1))){
          divs[i].style.display="none";
          divs[i].style.visibility='hidden';
       }else{
         divs[i].style.display="block";
         divs[i].style.visibility='visible';
       }
     }
   }

  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form action=".." ..>
<!-- the first page has style set to be visible -->
<div id="formpage_1" style="visibility: visible; display: block; .."> 
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- NEXT button -->
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(1);">
</div>

<!-- the 2nd and following pages have style set to be invisible -->
<div id="formpage_2"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none; ..">
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons -->
  <input type="button" value="back" onclick="pagechange(0);">
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(2);">
</div>
...
<div id="formpage_3"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none; ..">
  <label for="..">..</label>
  <input type=".." ..>
  ..
  <!-- PREVIOUS and SUBMIT buttons -->
  <input type="button" value="back" onclick="pagechange(1);">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am from china ,my QQ account 243030330

Answer (score 0):

this works quite nicely for tables (place this in `head`section)

```
<script>
function toggleTable() {
    var myTable = document.getElementById("yourTable");
    myTable.style.display = (myTable.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
}
</script>
```

then place a button to toggle table display on and off

```
<a id="toggleTableDisplay" onclick="toggleTable();" href="#">Show/Hide Table</a>
```

and the table definition

```
<table id="yourTable">...</table>
```

Comment: in case you want to start with a HIDDEN table `<table id="yourTable" style="display: none">`